# Python function body depends on the type of the argument class

Tags: python, design-patterns, dynamic, overloading, overload-resolution

I am new to python and object oriented programming and I stumbled into a problem which I believe can someone with more experience can answer easily.

I am writing a statistical package in Python and there are two  abstract classes for static and dynamic models, where the dynamic model class overloads some methods of the static model class. Moreover I have an estimation class which has call methods of the model class based on the type of the model class.

This is the simplified version of my first try on the setup:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class StaticModel():
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod   
    def LogObs(self,y):
        pass

class DynamicModel(StaticModel):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod   
    def LogObs(self,y,x):
        pass
    @abstractmethod   
    def LogTrans(self,x):
        pass    

class StaticModelExample(StaticModel):
    def LogObs(self,y):
        print 'StaticModel '+str(y)

class DynamicModelExample(DynamicModel): 
    def LogTrans(self,x):
        return x+1    

    def LogObs(self,y,x):
        print 'DynamicModel '+str(y)+' '+str(x)  

class EstimationMethod():
    def __init__(self,model,y):
        self.model=model
        self.y=y
        if(str(model.__class__.__base__).find('DynamicModel')!=-1):
            print 'It is a dynamic model'            
            self.x=0
        elif(str(self.model.__class__.__base__).find('StaticModel')!=-1):
            print 'It is a static model'

    def Estimate(self):
        if(str(self.model.__class__.__base__).find('StaticModel')!=-1):
            self.model.LogObs(self.y)
        elif(str(self.model.__class__.__base__).find('DynamicModel')!=-1):
            self.model.LogObs(self.y,self.x)
            self.x=self.model.LogTrans(self.x)
            print 'new x '+str(self.x)
        else:
            'model probably inherited from wrong class'




y=1        
modelStatic=StaticModelExample()
estimationStatic=EstimationMethod(modelStatic,y)
estimationStatic.Estimate()

modelDynamic=DynamicModelExample()
estimationDynamic=EstimationMethod(modelDynamic,y)
estimationDynamic.Estimate()
```

This sort of does the trick but I don't think this is the best way of doing it, because I always have to write if statement when ever I would like to do something in the estimation which is specific to the dynamic model.

Any suggestion for a better design pattern or a trick would simplify the code. I guess this should be standard.

Comment: You'd probably find https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance useful. Beginner's code that uses `isinstance` is usually broken by design.

Answer (score 1):

The model is responsible for the estimation.

```
class Model:
    def estimate(self):
        pass

class Static(Model):
    def estimate(self, x, y):
        self.LogObs()
        x = 0
        return x

class Dynamic(Model):
    def estimate(self, x, y):
        self.LogObs()
        x = self.LogTrans(y)
        return x
```

You're looking at the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

> The strategy pattern
>
> - defines a family of algorithms,
> - encapsulates each algorithm, and
> - makes the algorithms interchangeable within that family.

edit:

From your comment, it doesn't make sense in your domain to have the model perform the estimate. What you want are two `Estimator` classes, so instead of instantiating different models, you instantiate different estimators e.g:

```
class Estimator(object):
    def estimate(self):
        pass

class StaticEstimator(Estimator):
    def __init__():
        self.model = StaticModelExample()

    def estimate():
        self.model.LogObs()
        self.x = 0

class DynamicEstimator(Estimator):
    def __init__(y):
        self.y = y
        self.model = DynamicModelExample()

    def estimate():
        self.model.LogObs(self.y, self.x)
        self.x = self.model.LogTrans(self.x)
```

Comment: Hi Peter! Thanks for the reply. I am still trying to digest your answer. It seems that if I would use a Estimation base class and inherit a StaticEstimation and a DynamicEstimation class that would be pretty similar to what you are suggesting. If I understand correctly that would still classify as a strategy pattern (I am hesitant to put the estimation method in the model class because that is less intuitive from a statistical perspective).

Comment: Ah, I see. The strategy then should be between `Estimator`s, not `Model`s. The estimator will use a particular model.

Comment: Yes I think  that is the way to go. My only remaining issue is that some parts of the  estimation of static and dynamic models are quite similar (but not entirely for example the number of inputs are different for the LogObs method)  and I would "copy" some parts which is the sign of poor design.